# How to set value using system.refelection

Tags: c#, reflection

I would like to know, for the following code example, how I can assign values to myClass Obj, using Type.InvokeMember or with field.SetValue. The field name and value are represented as strings.

```
    class myClass
    {
        public string obj1;
        public string obj2;
    }

    class myClass2
    {
       public myClass obj = new myClass();
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type type = Type.GetType("ConsoleApp2.myClass2");

            object classObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            FieldInfo fi = type.GetField("obj");
            fi.SetValue(??????);
            type.InvokeMember("obj", BindingFlags.SetField, null, classObj , ?????);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple in your sample you should be able to do something like:

```
fi.SetValue(classObj, new myClass());
```

so in your case:

```
class myClass
{
    public string obj1;
    public string obj2;

}
class myClass2
{
    public myClass obj = new myClass();
}
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type type2 = Type.GetType("ConsoleApp1.myClass");
        object classObj2 = Activator.CreateInstance(type2);
        FieldInfo fi2 = type2.GetField("obj1");
        fi2.SetValue(classObj2 ,"some str1");
        FieldInfo fi3 = type2.GetField("obj2");
        fi3.SetValue(classObj2 ,"some str2");

        Type type = Type.GetType("ConsoleApp1.myClass2");
        object classObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        FieldInfo fi = type.GetField("obj");
        fi.SetValue(classObj,classObj2);

    }
}
```

Comment: with new myClass() it will initialize the object with null value. i have all the information in terms of string. i cannot directly do new myClass()

Comment: are your dependencies loaded at design time? can you do `typeof(myClass)`? or do you need to resolve everything by reflection?

Comment: No everything is loaded at runtime. I have the info myClass but in string form "myClass"

Comment: you already did something like that, but see my updated answer

Comment: Great it works perfectly fine. I just changed Type type2 = Type.GetType("ConsoleApp1.myClass2");  => myClass2 to myClass :-)

Answer (score 2):

This seems simple

```
fi.SetValue(classObj, "new value");
```

as stated in documentation.  Did this not work for you?

Comment: No it didnot work it generates the exception "System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'ConsoleApp2.myClass'.'" i want to set the value of obj1 and obj2

Comment: `fi` isn't a string field.

Comment: "new value" is string

Comment: @muhayyuddingillani -- you said in your question "The filed name and value are represented as strings."